# Prove $(A-B)-C=A-(B\cup C)$ Using Set Identities

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$$(A-B)-C=A-(B\cup C)$$

I have to use set identities to write an algebraic proof. Here is my attempt:
$$(A \cap B^{c})-C = A-(B\cup C)$$
$$(A \cap B^{c}) \cap C^{c} = A-(B\cup C)$$ 
$$A \cap (B^{c} \cap C^{c}) = A-(B\cup C)$$
$$A-(B\cup C)=A-(B\cup C)$$

I am not really sure if I did the last step right. I used the identity $A-B = A\cap B^{c}$. For the second to last line, is it possible to change $\cap (B^{c} \cap C^{c})$ into $-(B \cup C)$ using this identity? If this is incorrect, could someone explain how I would prove this.

Comment: What you've done is correct. But only because of De Morgan's Laws. $B^c \cap C^c = (B \cup C)^c $. Maybe start from the Left hand side of the equation and then obtain the right. I also assume you've been given $A - B = A \cap B^c$ and the Associative Law.

Comment: So when I have $(B\cap C)^{c}$ I cannot change it to $B \cup C$ (removing the complement and reversing intersection into union) but instead use DeMorgan's Law?

Comment: Nope.. That needn't be true. Draw a simple Venn Diagram with two intersecting sets to visualise it. $(B \cap C)^c$ is not equal to $B \cup C$ but to $B^c \cup C^c$..

Comment: Yes, you can--as long as you replace the preceding "$\cap$" with "$-$". But not generally, as @Ishfaaq says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the intermediate step is that $B^c\cap C^c = (B\cup C)^c$